# MySQLi multi_query won't work

Tags: php, mysql, iis-express

I have a problem by sending a multi_query to my MySQL database. I want to get the content of a file and send it to the database via a multi query

I made a MySQLi class with this method in it:

```
    public function multi_query($resource)
    {   
        $Timer  = microtime(true);
        if($this->MySQLiObj->multi_query($resource))
        {
            do {
                if ($result = $this->MySQLiObj->store_result())
                    $result->free();

                $this->queryCount++;

                if(!$this->MySQLiObj->more_results()){break;}

            } while ($this->MySQLiObj->next_result());      
        }

        $this->SQL[]    = $resource;

        if ($this->MySQLiObj->errno)
        {
            if($this->MySQLiObj->error == true) {
                echo "SQL Error: ".$this->MySQLiObj->error."<br><br>Query Code: ".$resource;
            } else {
                return "SQL Error: ".$this->MySQLiObj->error;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I'm using it:

```
    $mysqli = new \System\Database\MySQLi($_SESSION["server"], $_SESSION["username"], $_SESSION["password"], $_SESSION["database"], $_SESSION["port"]);
    echo $mysqli->multi_query(file_get_contents('install.sql'));
```

And here is my .sql file:

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

CREATE TABLE `t_User`
(
    `p_ID` INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `m_Firstname` VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
    `m_Surename` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    `m_Email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `m_Password` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
    `m_ActivationCode` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `m_Activated` BIT DEFAULT 0,
    `m_Online` BIT DEFAULT 0,
    `m_LastActivity` DATETIME,
    `m_Birthdate` DATE,
    `m_ProfilPicture` VARCHAR(255),
    `m_SchoolID` INT(11),
    `m_AddressID` INT(11),
    `m_IsAdmin` BIT DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (`p_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `t_School`
(
    `p_ID` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `m_Name` VARCHAR(150) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    `m_Description` VARCHAR(255),
    `m_Homepage` VARCHAR(150) UNIQUE,
    `m_AddressID` INT,
    `m_ManagerID` INT NOT NULL UNIQUE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And here is my error:

SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '﻿SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"; /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CL' at line 1

It doesn't matter if I delete the complete first line.
And I also tried to copy the content of the file into a php variable...but it doesn'T work either.

Hope anybody can help me :/

Comment: a wild guess. don't you have a BOM signature at the top of your file?

Comment: what is a BOM signature??

Comment: let me google that for you: http://google.com/search?q=BOM+signature

Comment: Oh okey...My bad^^
Should have googled it for mysqelf -.-"

Answer (score 3):

Speaking of **`mysqli_multi_query`**, it works all right for me:

```
$q = <<<HERE
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

CREATE TABLE `t_User`
(
    `p_ID` INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `m_Firstname` VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
    `m_Surename` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    `m_Email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `m_Password` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
    `m_ActivationCode` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `m_Activated` BIT DEFAULT 0,
    `m_Online` BIT DEFAULT 0,
    `m_LastActivity` DATETIME,
    `m_Birthdate` DATE,
    `m_ProfilPicture` VARCHAR(255),
    `m_SchoolID` INT(11),
    `m_AddressID` INT(11),
    `m_IsAdmin` BIT DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (`p_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
HERE;

$m = mysqli_connect('localhost','test','aaa','test');
$m->multi_query($q);
var_dump($m->error);
```

- no errors raised, table created. So, this function apparently works.

Comment: This works for me too...But what's the difference if I write $q = <<<  HERE
...sql...
HERE;
And when I write $q = file_get_contents('install.sql');
It just won't work that way :/

Comment: then you have to compare these 2 texts. output them in urlencode, compare lengths, etc.

Comment: okey...now I know the problem...At the beginning of the string from the file there is a BOM signature... %EF%BB%BF
so I substr the string and finally it works^^
$m->multi_query(substr(file_get_contents('install.sql')), 3);
I don't know if this is the best way to do it...but it works...
Thanks for your help debuging my problem!